# Go/Fyne app crashes on hook.End() call using gohook

Tags: go, fyne

I ran into a problem while using Go's [Fyne](https://fyne.io) toolkit and [robotn/gohook](https://github.com/robotn/gohook) package.

Following function gets invoked on a button click to select/pick a color:

```
func mouse(data *[]string) {

    hook.Register(hook.MouseMove, []string{}, func(e hook.Event) {
        // ...
    })
    
    hook.Register(hook.MouseDown, []string{}, func(e hook.Event) {
        c := robotgo.GetPixelColor(int(e.X), int(e.Y))
        *data = append(*data, c)
        hook.End()
    })
    
    s := hook.Start()
    <-hook.Process(s)
}
```

If I click on a button consecutively fast, program will crash:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
\[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x48 pc=0x7f07d67c5240\]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0xb94904?, 0x6d?})
/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/panic.go:992 +0x71
runtime.sigpanic()
/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:802 +0x3a9

goroutine 179 \[syscall\]:
runtime.cgocall(0xa29a20, 0xc0000bde08)
/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x5c fp=0xc0000bdde0 sp=0xc0000bdda8 pc=0x42ecfc
github.com/robotn/gohook.\_Cfunc_stop_event()
\_cgo_gotypes.go:138 +0x48 fp=0xc0000bde08 sp=0xc0000bdde0 pc=0xa1e2a8
github.com/robotn/gohook.End()
/home/dachi/go/pkg/mod/github.com/robotn/gohook@v0.40.0/hook.go:247 +0x37 fp=0xc0000bde30 sp=0xc0000bde08 pc=0xa1f437
main.mouse.func2({0x8, {0xc112eb2c66971430, 0x18158c65e, 0x139f440}, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, ...})
/home/dachi/Code/go-colorpicker/main.go:103 +0x1c5 fp=0xc0000bdeb8 sp=0xc0000bde30 pc=0xa20dc5
github.com/robotn/gohook.Process.func1()
/home/dachi/go/pkg/mod/github.com/robotn/gohook@v0.40.0/hook.go:147 +0x26f fp=0xc0000bdfe0 sp=0xc0000bdeb8 pc=0xa1e8af
runtime.goexit()
/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571 +0x1 fp=0xc0000bdfe8 sp=0xc0000bdfe0 pc=0x48f0a1
created by github.com/robotn/gohook.Process
/home/dachi/go/pkg/mod/github.com/robotn/gohook@v0.40.0/hook.go:133 +0xad
```

I believe this problem occurs because of `hook.End()` call.

I'm relatively new to Go, but I tried executing `mouse` function in a separate Goroutine but it did not help.

You can view a repository and code if you like [go-colorpicker](https://github.com/dachinat/go-colorpicker)